# Prevent Character Escape When Calling XmlWriter.WriteElementString

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have  a string:

```xml
<entry key="Provider">Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.</entry>
<entry key="Challenged">No</entry>
```

I want to output this string using `XmlWriter.WriteElementString()`. The problem here is that `XmlWriter.WriteElementString()` will escape all `<` and `>` characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I have checked MSDN to see if there is a way to disable that from happening but have not found an answer.

Is there a way to disable the auto-escaping that is occuring?

Answer (score 9):

Using the [XmlWriter.WriteRaw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeraw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to output the text resolved my problem.

Comment: Just bear in mind that if your string contains a character that needs to be escaped, this method will write invalid XML. For example, try using "AT&T", and then try to parse the XML. the parser might crack on the "&".  If you work with the writer methods(see my answer below), then the writer will ensure that your values are always encoded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the XML you'd like to have? Are you trying to write XML inside of XML? Something like this:

```
<outer>
    <entry key="Provider">Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.</entry>
    <entry key="Challenged">No</entry>
</outer>
```

In that case, you don't want to use `WriteElementString`. Use one of the overloads of [XmlWriter.WriteNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd6aw1b.aspx).

Comment: I am builing the xml from ad adbo.data reader . one of the column has xml data. That data need to be written to the xml element without escpases.
Writenode only help if XmlTextReader  is used

Comment: What is the data type of the column? varchar or something?

Comment: The datatype is a varchar. However I am appending all the contenct from the datareader to a stringbuilder object. once all the data is gathered from the 8 column in the dataready. I write the string to the xml.  The problme with xmlwirter.writenode is that it requires a xmlreader as one of the parameter in the methods. I am not reading data from xmlready to begin with. Hence, this method call would not apply.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ibrar: since the column is varchar, you're ok. If you were using SQL Server 2005 or later, I'd suggest you use a column with the "XML" datatype. In that case, you can retrieve an actual `XmlReader` from the database for each column. That would have allowed you to use `WriteNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the actual XML you are trying to write? (not a literal inside of XML)?

Try this:

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("entry");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("key", "Provider");
xmlWriter.WriteValue("Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.")
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
```